# on Pause starts audio from starting not where i paused

Tags: android, audio

this is my code, which i am using to pause song and to play where it has been left, but it always playing song from starting not where it has been paused, why ?

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

public void play(){  

            try {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strNURL);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            mediaPlayer.start();

              ....................
       }

       public void pause(){ 
          mediaPlayer.pause();
          btnPause.setEnabled(false);
          btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
       }
```

I have placed my whole code, i am allowing user to do tap on any of the item in the listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem is due to you are reseting your mediaplayer on play method remove `mediaPlayer.reset();`

for more

you can use methods getcurrentposition to play from last position

```
     public void pause(){ 
     current_position=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
          mediaPlayer.pause();
          btnPause.setEnabled(false);
          btnPlay.setEnabled(true);
       }  


    public void play(){ 

        mp.prepare();   
        mp.seekTo(current_position); 
        mp.start(); 
       }
```

Comment: thanks :) your second solution worked for me -- use an integer variable to get current position of mediaplayer